# Download custom libraries from Target in TwinCAT 3

Tags: twincat

I have downloaded a project form a PLC and some libraries will be downloaded but not the custom libraries. Here there are two unknown libraries:

[image: libraries]

I can choose for The library Tc3_EventLogger the last version or go into _libraries and install the same version.

[image: directory]

We find under the project (waschmodul) and _Libraries this:

[image]

The library "TcLog" is another custom library. However this library was already installed. If I didnt installed it, it wouldn´t have founded here like TcExt.

I cannot find the custom library TcExt. Is there anyway to download it? I have the source code but I didnt find any option.

Comment: Is there another directory in _Libraries besides "beckhoff automation gmbh"? When I download a project from target there is a separate directory for each library provider in _Libraries, including custom made libraries.

Comment: I assume no directories from _Libraries contains TcExt.library, right? Only thing that comes to mind is:

1. On the PLC go to C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Boot\CurrentConfig You can do it using remote desktop, SD card reader, C-FAST card reader etc.

2. Copy all the tpzip files to your machine

3. Unpack them using 7zip and look for your library file inside

Comment: Updated. I checked the file: C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Boot\CurrentConfig. Its not inside

Comment: Unfortunately, that's all I had. Have you contacted Beckhoff support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contated Beckhoff support. Solved! "Source Libraries" muss be activated under the project and settings:

[image]

Comment: Just for clarification: This option has to set when you download the code to the target system. The related libraries will be placed in C:\TwinCAT\3.1\Boot. If the box is unchecked no library will be stored in the boot-folder and you are not able to load it back because it does not exist. In this case, you have to get this library from somewhere else.

Comment: Didn't work for me, still missing library tc3_interfaces after